# Login page rendering value even when the user in not logged in

Tags: angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am working on an angular app and implementing registration and logging functionality in it using Firebase. Both functionalties are working fine.

Now the trouble that I am having is in onAuthStateChanged() function. What I want is once a user is logged in, he/she must be able to see a message saying that they are logged in. I am even able to see "Hi {{currentUser.firstname}}" that I have mentioned in the code once I log in but as soon as I refresh the page and try to log in again, I see that "Hi {{currentUser.firstname}}" even when I do not click the login button. I don't know how my login page is rendering $rootScope.currentUser value even when I haven't logged in. I have written the following code for it

JS

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var data = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
            data.on('value', function(snapshot) {       
            var userobj=snapshot.val(); 
            $rootScope.currentUser=userobj;
         })} else {
            // No user is signed in.
            $rootScope.currentUser=' ';
          }
        });
```

html

```
<div class="userinfo" ng-show="currentUser">
    <span class="userinfo">Hi {{currentUser.firstname}}</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is by-design. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users):

> The Firebase Auth instance persists the user's state, so that refreshing the page (in a browser) or restarting the application doesn't lose the user's information.

If you do not want the users's auth state to be persisted, you will need to sign out the user.

Comment: I implemented the logout functionality. I am able to lose the Auth reference due to sign out but user object is still functional . And I think because of this I am seeing "Hi {{currentUser.firstname}}" on my login page even after logging out. Am I right on this? @cartant

Comment: After signing out, the `user` passed from `onAuthStateChanged` should be `null`. The most likely explanation is that Angular's change detection has not seen the change to `currentUser`. I guess you need to call `$apply` - or whatever (it's been a while since I developed in Angular 1).